# Try{}catch для XMLHttpRequest (404)

Tags: http-status-code-404, javascript, xmlhttprequest

С помощью одного (объявляется единожды) `XMLHttpRequest` загружаю файлы, данные на которые берутся из "стека", в этом проблем нет.

Проблема в следующем: когда `XMLHttpRequest.send` не находит файл, то вылазит ошибка  Not Found, после которой функция не работает. Пробовал через try catch уловить ошибку, чтобы, так сказать, машина не блокировала эту функцию после получения ею ошибки, но это ничего не дало, как будто .send() не реагирует на try.

Как это исправить? Желательно без повторного объявления `XMLHttpRequest()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, был чисто мой косяк. )))

Поставил переменную для проверки на доступность функции для загрузки.
При true функция может стартовать, стартует и меняет значение на false, по окончанию выполнения меняет его обратно на true, и вот после ошибки просто некому менять значение этой переменной.

Answer (score 0):

[[@Ni55aN](/users/20555/ni55an)](/users/20555/ni55an), `XMLHttpRequest` не бросает ошибок, если запрос возвращает код 404 (или любой другой). Проблема либо в обработчике результата (`onreadystatechange`), либо в том, что вы используете один и тот же объект `XMLHttpRequest` для нескольких запросов (проблема IE), либо в нарушении кросс-доменной политики. Выложите ваш код на http://jsfiddle.net/ и объясните, почему использование нескольких объектов `XMLHttpRequest` для вас нежелательно.